# Moving From HTTPS Page To HTTP Page Breaks The Website

Tags: php, ssl, wordpress, ssl-certificate

I use [iThemes Security (formerly Better WP Security)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) to force ssl on the log-in, admin pages, and on a certain front-end pages.

If you go to [our contact page](https://mostasharoon.org/contact/) for example then clicked on the HOME page in firefox or opera the website will breaks!

Can any anyone help me solve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are loading non SSL lelements on an SSL page. Just make sure your entire site (including all resources) are loaded over SSL.

Comment: Thank you. But the home page none https page why loaded as https page?

Comment: In chrome nothing breaks!

Comment: The problem returned :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :)

It was incorrect [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) configuration with ssl, for more information visit [this article](https://www.w3-edge.com/weblog/2014/08/w3-total-cache-and-https/).

Thanks for everyone tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The home link is in the https://... format and one the homepage you're loading stylesheets over regular http so the browser blocks them. You have 2 choices:

Either force the home link to not use http by replacing

```
<a href="https://mostasharoon.org/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound-widget-int', 'https://mostasharoon.org/', 'HOME']);">HOME</a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://mostasharoon.org/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound-widget-int', 'https://mostasharoon.org/', 'HOME']);">HOME</a>
```

Or make sure all the CSS / JS files are loaded via HTTPS on the homepage.

Comment: Thank you. I did that (hard coded the home link) but that solve it for the front-end only, but all the links on the website still https even the links in the menu, I don't want to hard-coded all these links, All plugins and theme that I used uses the default WordPress function to enque the scripts and styles.

Comment: I noticed that if I logged-in in firefox for example the browser doesn't do that!